# Visual studio publish disabled on a MAUI project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, maui, msix

I opened, after 5 months, a .Net 6 Maui project done in August.
I needed to change *just a label* and create an msix, as usual.
But today I see that the Visual Studio 2022's publish button is disabled.

Any idea to solve it?

Thank you so much

John

I tried to

- delete the publish folders and its configurations
- delete the bin and obj.
- check for something missing in the proj properties
- delete the .vs content

hoping to enable it again.

What else...

- All softwares and OS are up to date.
- Its target is for windows OS
- If I create a brand new project for Maui, publish button works.

UPDATE:
Checking destination for Android and iOS into the project's properties page, enables the publish button again.

Comment: You can try to [publish with the CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/windows/deployment/publish-cli?view=net-maui-7.0). Or create a new project and then migrate the code to the new project.

Comment: Yes, I fear I'll do this. tnx so much

Comment: In my experience, I disabled everything but Windows and the publish option is disabled. If you enable Android even though you may not be using it, the publish option will be enabled. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had only windows target framework in my .csproj file. I added `net8.0-android` and Publish button became enabled.